What is the correct syntax to use for a custom claim in an Entra Verified ID rule definition?
I've set up an Entra External ID system, and created a Custom Security Attribute in order to simulate adding custom data to the users who login to my app.  (Just a demo at the moment, but hoping to store membership number and membership level in there).  I'm trying to use that custom attribute/claim info to be able to issue Verified Credentials that contain their membership number, however it always fails with the same error "Missing provided claims in issuance" - it works fine with using a non-custon field (such as given_name, as per all the examples)
I've tried with Foo.Bar, user.Bar, extension_..._Bar but having no luck.
What is the syntax needed in the Verified Credential rule?
Current failing rule:
{
  "attestations": {
    "idTokenHints": [
      {
        "mapping": [
          {
            "outputClaim": "foobar",
            "required": true,
            "inputClaim": "Foo.Bar",
            "indexed": false
          }
        ],
        "required": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "validityInterval": 2592000,
  "vc": {
    "type": [
      "Foobar"
    ]
  }
}

Error from Issue api using the demo 1-asp-net-core-api-idtokenhint C# project:
issuance error: "Something went wrong calling the API: 
{
  "requestId": "2b020237faffd90eaed9d034a296775e",
  "date": "Tue, 21 May 2024 22:43:44 GMT",
  "mscv": "cpMoovB/XjpznKMR.3",
  "error": {
    "code": "badRequest",
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "innererror": {
      "code": "badOrMissingField",
      "message": "Missing provided claims in issuance: [Foo.Bar]",
      "target": "claims"
    }
  }
}"

Custom Attribute setup:

User configuration:


This is the syntax for both files so you can successfully issue and verify credentials with custom claims.
Display definition:
{
  "locale": "en-US",
  "card": {
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
    "description": "With verified patient card you can sign in faster and access your medical data.",
    "issuedBy": "Formula Healthcare",
    "textColor": "#055C9D",
    "title": "Verified Patient",
    "logo": {
      "description": "Formula Healthcare Logo",
      "uri": "https://strf5verifiediddev.blob.core.windows.net/vc-public/fh-logo.png"
    }
  },
  "consent": {
    "instructions": "Accept credential to confirm that you are verified patient.",
    "title": "Accept credential for Verified Patients"
  },
  "claims": [
    {
      "claim": "vc.credentialSubject.fullName",
      "label": "Full name",
      "type": "String"
    },
    {
      "claim": "vc.credentialSubject.nationalHealthcareId",
      "label": "National Healthcare ID",
      "type": "String"
    }
  ]
}

Rules definition:
{
  "attestations": {
    "idTokenHints": [
      {
        "mapping": [
          {
            "outputClaim": "fullName",
            "required": false,
            "inputClaim": "fullName",
            "indexed": false
          },
          {
            "outputClaim": "nationalHealthcareId",
            "required": false,
            "inputClaim": "nationalHealthcareId",
            "indexed": false
          }
        ],
        "required": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "validityInterval": 2592000,
  "vc": {
    "type": [
      "VerifiedPatient"
    ]
  }
}

As you can see above you can create mappings for claims in VC (and use different names than initially defined, using input and output claim definition). However, I recommend to use the same names for both, input and output claims.
I hope this helps.
